# Prove that $\lVert \exp(A) - \exp(B) \rVert \leq \lVert A-B \rVert e^{\max\{\lVert A \rVert, \lVert B \rVert \}}$

Tags: normed-spaces

, where A and B are square Matrices, exp(A) is the matrix exponential

I can see where the $\lVert A-B \rVert$ comes from, but can't figure out how to get the $ e^{max\{\lVert A \rVert, \lVert B \rVert\}} $. The definition for the matrix exponential we're using is the following:
$\exp(A)= \sum \frac{A^k}{k!}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by restating the following inequality.
**Lemma**:
$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have:
$$ \| A^n -B^n \| \le n \|A-B\| c^{n-1}$$
where $c= \max( \| A \|, \| B\| )$.
**Demonstration** (Outline) 
It's just a direct consequence of the submultiplicity of $\| \|$. For example, for $n=3$ , $$ A^3-B^3 = (A-B)A^2+B(A-B)A+B^2(A-B)$$
$\square$
Then you can see that:
$$ \| \exp(A) -\exp(B) \| \le \sum_{n \ge 1} \| A^n-B^n \| \dfrac{1}{n!}$$

The rest is simple $\square$ 
**Remark**: A similar proof by MVT like given by mathecounterexample can also be carried out, some final arguments must ofcourse be completed by using the submultiplicity.

Comment: Thank you! We were told to use the telescopic sum $ A^{n+1} - B^{n+1} = \sum A^k(A-B)B^{n-k}$, which intuitively has the same sense as your Lemma. I wonder how one follows from each other?

Comment: @byk303: I'm not sure if I can understand clearly your question, would you mind more elaborating?

Comment: The expression in my previous comment was given to me as a Lemma to use in the proof of the main expression in my question. Do you have any idea how I can base my proof around this particular hint, instead of the Lemma you used? Both Lemmas look similar, but are not quite the same.

Comment: Thanks. To me, if that identity is the central idea of the demonstration, then using or not using my lemma does not matter much to the meaning of your proof. So if you want to apply directly that identity to lemma, it can be done as follows.

Comment: We have: $$  \exp(A) -\exp(B)  = \sum_{ n \ge 0 } \sum_{ k=0}^n A^k(A-B)A^{n-k} \dfrac{1}{(n+1)!}$$ Hence $$\| \exp(A) -\exp(B) \| \le \sum_{ n \ge 0 } \sum_{ k=0}^n |A|^k|A-B| |B|^{n-k} \dfrac{1}{(n+1)!} \le |A-B| \exp( \max( |A|,|B|))$$

Comment: So you see, it's kinda the same proof, however, I don't prefer this approach as there may be some ambiguities when we think of the well-definedness of the very first infinite sum.

Comment: Thank you very much, that has fully answered my question. If you don't mind, could you elaborate when/why the first infinite sum wouldn't be sufficiently well-defined?

Comment: You're welcome. it's because the question of well-definedness of the infinite sum is more or less the same thing we were trying to prove.

Comment: You see, in order for the sum $\sum_n A_n$ to be well defined, we should have some bound concerning the sum, and the usual condition we use is $ \sum_n |A_n| < +\infty$ .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117085/discussion-between-byk303-and-paresseux-nguyen).

Answer (score 0):

**Partial answer**

Define

$$F(t) = \exp((1-t)A + tB)$$ for $t\in [0,1]$. According to the Mean Value Theorem

$$\Vert \exp(A) - \exp(B) \Vert = \Vert F(1) - F(0) \Vert \le \sup_{t \in [0,1]} \Vert F^\prime(t) \Vert \vert 1 - 0 \vert =\sup_{t \in [0,1]} \Vert F^\prime(t) \Vert$$

As $$F^\prime(t) = \exp((1-t)A + tB) \cdot (B-A)$$ we're left to prove that

$$\sup_{t \in [0,1]} \Vert \exp((1-t)A + tB) \Vert \le e^{\max(\Vert A \Vert,\Vert B \Vert)}$$ which is clear if $A,B$ commutes as in this case
$$\exp((1-t)A + tB) = \exp((1-t)A) \exp(tB).$$

If not, I don't see how to conclude...